Detached Metal Shop Panel Feeder
I have a manufactured detached portable metal shop. I have a 15amp 110v window air conditioner in summer and 15amp 110v heater in winter, 15amp 110v air compressor and will be using various carpenter tools. Maybe a table saw in the future. It came with a 125amp 16 space Eaton panel with a double 100amp breaker disconnect. It has one 20amp 220 breaker for small compressor. Two 20amps breakers that feed 6 outlets and 2 led lights.
The panel has a 1" PVC LB Conduit Body coming into it from outside. The meter that feeds the house is 16' from the shop. I want to bury the conduit 24" so will end up needing 34' of feeder wire. The conduit will be straight down from LB Conduit Body, 90-degree elbow toward meter, 90-degree elbow up and into meter.

Since the building already has a 1” PVC LB Conduit Body can I get by with 1" PVC conduit?
What size and type of wire will be required? (also copper vs aluminum)
Is any special grounding required?


You start with your main panel and do a load calculation(google, find online).  That will show the size of the feeder breaker you can go up to.  Metal conduit would save needing a ground wire, but probably will not make a difference.  2-2-2-4 AL usually gives the best bang for a buck and is good to 90 amps.  A panel can be fed by a smaller feed breaker than its rating  The rating is just the max.
